# how do i load a page into a string with Soup.SessionAsync without the use of callbacks

Tags: string, html, gjs

I've made a nice desklet which among other things load a page from a url into a variable like this

```
    let url = 'http://localhost/page.php';
let file = Gio.file_new_for_uri(url).load_contents(null);
let doc=(file[1]+"")
return doc;
```

This work great on localhost. the problem is when i acces something over the internet. entire linux freeze for like 1 sec every time the loop acces this page. So i was thinking to use the async method. Of course im not sure if this will solve the problem for me cause im not very sure it does what i think it does.But the problem is that all my examples are with callbacks which im having a hard time to understand...the function works...but the result vanish the moment im done with this function..so question is simple:
Is there any way to return the mes variable in the getpage function?

```
getpage: function() {
  let url = 'http://localhost/page.php';
  let message = Soup.Message.new('GET', url)
_httpSession.queue_message(message, function(session, message) {
  let mes = message.response_body.data;
  });
  //like thie 
  return mes+"";
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's an async method, you can't have access to the `mes` variable in the `getpage` function.
Here is the execution order of the `getpage` function:

1. creation of the Soup Message object
2. register the function in queue message, but don't execute it for the moment end `getpage` function.
3. At this point `mes` variable doesn't exist

When the url will be downloaded, the function registered in the queue message will be executed and the `mes` variable will be set, but in another scope that the `getpage` function.
That's the way async functions with callbacks work.

So my suggestion is to use a real callback function and to do your treatments in it:

```
getpage: function() {
  let url = 'http://localhost/page.php';
  let message = Soup.Message.new('GET', url)
  _httpSession.queue_message(message, real-callback);
},

real-callback: function(session, message) {
  let mes = message.response_body.data;
  /* do here what you wanted to do at the end of getpage fonction */
}
```